# Non blocking blpop from redis in perl

Tags: perl, redis

I have a program that runs in a continuous loop

```
Pick one job from a Redis using BLPOP
Process the job,
LOOP
```

What I need to do is
While the job is in process get the next job so that I can save the time used up for redis blpop .. how can I do this

Comment: This sounds like a premature optimization to me.  How much time is spent in BLPOP (assuming an item is already present in the queue)?  It should be negligible compared to the time spend performing the work (otherwise there's some question as to why you're dispatching the work through Redis).

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
do forever
   BLPOP next job     # from Redis
   wait               # for all background jobs to finish      
   process job &      # process job in the background
done
```